# RestTemplate postForEntity return List of DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot

im working ina spring project and using restemplate to call POST API that take a List of DTOOne And return a List of DTOTWO.

this is my code :

```
  List<MYDTOONE> listDTORequest;
  //values..
  
  ResponseEntity<List<MYDTOOTWO>> userActionsResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity("my yrl",
    listDTORequest, MYDTOOTWO.class);
```

im geeting a Syntax error in the last param i need to know how i can tell postForEntity that im waiting for  List.

i tried also `List<MYDTOOTWO>` in the last paramater but still syntax error

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following `new ParameterizedTypeReference<List< MyDtoTwo>>() {}` instead of MYDTOOTWO.class (MyDtoTwo written for ease of reading) with the `exchange` method (UPDATE: postForEntity has parameterizedTypeReference removed).

What happens in your case is the response you get back is parsed as MYDTOOTWO.class however you're trying to interpret the result as a list, resulting in a mismatch. With parameterized type reference, you can specify that you're expecting a list of MYDTOOTWO.class instead.

Your call should be:

```
ResponseEntity<List<MYDTOOTWO>> userActionsResponse = exchange("my yrl", HttpMethod.POST,
    listDTORequest, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List< MYDTOOTWO>>() {});

List<MYDTOTWO> body = userActionsResponse.getBody();
```

UPDATE (as suggested by OP):
If you notice, you will need to send the HttpMethod.POST when making a POST request (as the second argument) and wrap your headers and request data in an HttpEntity requestEntity object as follows:

`HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(listDTORequest, headers);`

Comment: thanks @Sbsatter for your response . the ParameterizedTypeReference works only for getForEntity my call request is POST. i have a compilation error

Comment: Hi @James, I updated my answer. postForEntity has parameterizedTypeReference removed. You need to use exchange method now (and specify HttpMethod.POST. Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: i think with exchange POST we miss the HttpEntity that should contains listDTORequest ?

Comment: The signature of exchange method is:
exchange(
                                      String url,
                                      HttpMethod method,
                                      @Nullable
                                      HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
                                      ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType,
                                      Object... uriVariables).
HttpEntity (request entity) is the 3rd parameter. If you're facing any error, please add a stacktrace for me to look over.

Comment: Did you try using the code segment I shared? @James

Comment: yes . i added       HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(listDTORequest, headers); and it works

Comment: Great to know. Would've expected this to be the selected answer though as it's the RestTemplate way of handling things.

Comment: in fact i accepted your answer but please add the part : HttpEntity...

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the cleanest code, but it is the fastest and simplest way I have found to do it. You read it as an Array and then put it in the List.

```
List<MYDTOONE> listDTORequest;

// JDK8
List<MYDTOOTWO> userActionsResponse = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.postForEntity("my url", listDTORequest, MYDTOOTWO[].class).getBody());

// JDK9+
List<MYDTOOTWO> userActionsResponse = List.of(restTemplate.postForEntity("my url", listDTORequest, MYDTOOTWO[].class).getBody());
```